# Could hiding and displaying div with jQuery for a radio option be made simpler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio input and based on the selection, the displayed result changes. I have used the css `display: none;` to hide the `div` not associated with the result and remove the css `display: none;` when the `div` corresponds to the result.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").change(function() {

        var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
        if (IVAccess == 0) {
            $('#IVAccessBp').removeClass('displayNone');
        } else {
            $('#IVAccessBp').addClass('displayNone');
        }
        if (IVAccess == 1) {
            $('#IVAccessNBp').removeClass('displayNone');
        } else {
            $('#IVAccessNBp').addClass('displayNone');
        }

    });
    $("#apgarA2").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessB" value="0"/>
<label for="IVAccessB" class="apgarL">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessNB" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="IVAccessNB" class="apgarL">Option 2</label>
<div id="IVAccessBp" class="displayNone">
   Option 1      
</div>
<div id="IVAccessNBp" class="displayNone">
   Option 2      
</div>
```

My question is instead of writing the logic for `if (IVAccess == 0)` once for value `0` and then writing again for `if (IVAccess == 1)` for value `1`, can I write a simpler formula for both of the values? (It doesn't necessarily have to be only 2 options, somewhere may be it could be more than 2 options). I mean can this section be written in a smarter way?

```
var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
        if (IVAccess == 0) {
            $('#IVAccessBp').removeClass('displayNone');
        } else {
            $('#IVAccessBp').addClass('displayNone');
        }
        if (IVAccess == 1) {
            $('#IVAccessNBp').removeClass('displayNone');
        } else {
            $('#IVAccessNBp').addClass('displayNone');
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, its posible, you can use toggleClass(), instead of using remove and addClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ther could only be two values `0` and `1`, just use one single `if-else`:

```
var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
if (IVAccess == 0) {
    $('#IVAccessBp').removeClass('displayNone');
    $('#IVAccessNBp').addClass('displayNone');
} else {
    $('#IVAccessBp').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#IVAccessNBp').removeClass('displayNone');
}
```

Furthermore, you can use a ternary operator to decide which of the two elements gets `displayNone` and which does not, like so:

```
var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
$('#IVAccess' + (IVAccess == 0? "Bp": "NBp")).removeClass('displayNone');
$('#IVAccess' + (IVAccess == 1? "Bp": "NBp")).addClass('displayNone');
```

**EDIT:**

If there are more elements, then it's better to use a common class for the `"#IVAccess??"` elements so that hiding them all is only done using a single line of code. To show the corresponding element, you can either use an array of IDs and show the one that its index is the value of `IVAccess`, like so:

```
var arrayOfIDs = ['Bp', 'NBp', 'SomeOtherBp', 'YetAnotherBp'];

$("input").change(function() {
    var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
    $('.IVAccessCommonClass').addClass('displayNone');                  // hide all '#IVAccess??' elements using the common class
    $('#IVAccess' + arrayOfIDs[IVAccess]).removeClass('displayNone');   // show only the one corresponding to the current value of the input using that value as an index of the array
});
```

Or get rid of the array and change the values of the inputs to be the IDs themselves:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();           // this will be either 'Bp', 'NBp', ...
    $('.IVAccessCommonClass').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#IVAccess' + IVAccess).removeClass('displayNone');
});
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
    var IVAccess = $('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val();
    $('.IVAccessCommonClass').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#IVAccess' + IVAccess).removeClass('displayNone');
  });
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="IVAccess" value="B" /> Option B</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="IVAccess" value="SomeB" /> Option SomeB</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="IVAccess" value="SomeOtherB" /> Option SomeOtherB</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="IVAccess" value="NB" checked="checked" />Option NB</label>
<div id="IVAccessB" class="displayNone IVAccessCommonClass">
  Option B
</div>
<div id="IVAccessSomeB" class="displayNone IVAccessCommonClass">
  Option SomeB
</div>
<div id="IVAccessSomeOtherB" class="displayNone IVAccessCommonClass">
  Option SomeOtherB
</div>
<div id="IVAccessNB" class="displayNone IVAccessCommonClass">
  Option NB
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the response. But I'm sorry for the fuzzy question. What if there were more than 2 options?

Comment: @Ashonko If there are more, then you could use a common class for the `"#IVAccess??"` elements to hide them all in a single line of code, then use an array of names to only show the corresponding element, where the array is accessed using `IVAccess` value. Do you want me to post an example?

Comment: That would be very helpful. @ibrahim

Comment: @Ashonko Added two ways of acheiving that.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments about what each step is doing.

- I modified the markup to include a `data-value` to correspond to the radio values.
- Modified to include a class on the displayable areas for selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //select the displayable areas and cache it
  var $displays = $('.IVAccess');
  
  $("input").change(function(e) {
    //hide all of them
    $displays.addClass('displayNone');
    //find the element that matches the data-value, and show it
    $displays.filter(function(){
      return $(this).data('value') == e.target.value;
    }).removeClass('displayNone');
  });
  
  $("#apgarA2").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessB" value="0" />
<label for="IVAccessB" class="apgarL">Option 1</label>

<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessNB" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="IVAccessNB" class="apgarL">Option 2</label>

<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessNC" value="2" checked="checked" />
<label for="IVAccessNC" class="apgarL">Option 3</label>

<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessND" value="3" checked="checked" />
<label for="IVAccessND" class="apgarL">Option 4</label>

<div id="IVAccessBp" class="IVAccess displayNone" data-value="0">
  Option 1
</div>

<div id="IVAccessNBp" class="IVAccess displayNone" data-value="1">
  Option 2
</div>

<div id="IVAccessNCp" class="IVAccess displayNone" data-value="2">
  Option 3
</div>

<div id="IVAccessNDp" class="IVAccess displayNone" data-value="3">
  Option 4
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. This is a very interesting solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('#IVAccessBp').toggleClass('displayNone', IVAccess == 0 || IVAccess == 1);
```

Or

```
var values = [0,1];
$('#IVAccessBp').toggleClass('displayNone', values.indexOf(IVAccess) == -1);
```

You could add any value to the array *values* if the values could be other than 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another option slightly more different than the once above.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").change(function() {
        var IVAccess = Number($('input[name="IVAccess"]:checked').val());
        IVAccess ?  $('#IVAccessBp').hide() && $('#IVAccessNBp').show() : $('#IVAccessBp').show() && $('#IVAccessNBp').hide()
    });
    $("#apgarA2").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessB" value="0"/>
<label for="IVAccessB" class="apgarL">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" class="apgarIn" name="IVAccess" id="IVAccessNB" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="IVAccessNB" class="apgarL">Option 2</label>
<div id="IVAccessBp" hidden> 
   Option 1      
</div>
<div id="IVAccessNBp" hidden>
   Option 2      
</div>
```